# Saving the Generated Array

Tags: java

How do I define/store the generated array?

My goal is to print uncommon elements from two sorted arrays (the given array with the generated one, but I need it defined/stored).

```
if(arr[i]==unknown[?]){
```

Here's the complete code:

```
class Program  { 

public static void main (String[] args) { 
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
                  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 }; 
    int n = arr.length; 
    System.out.println("Sorted array is"); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); 
    generateWorstCase(arr, 0, n - 1); 
    System.out.println("\nInput array that will result in \n"+ 
         "worst case of merge sort is \n"); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); 
}
static void join(int arr[], int left[], int right[], int l, int m, int r)  { 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i <= m - l; i++) 
        arr[i] = left[i]; 
    for (int j = 0; j < r - m; j++) 
        arr[i + j] = right[j]; 
} 

static void split(int arr[], int left[], int right[], int l, int m, int r) { 
    for (int i = 0; i <= m - l; i++) 
        left[i] = arr[i * 2]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < r - m; i++) 
        right[i] = arr[i * 2 + 1]; 
} 

static void generateWorstCase(int arr[], int l, int r) { 
    if (l < r) { 
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2; 
        int[] left = new int[m - l + 1]; 
        int[] right = new int[r - m]; 
        split(arr, left, right, l, m, r); 
        generateWorstCase(left, l, m); 
        generateWorstCase(right, m + 1, r); 
        join(arr, left, right, l, m, r); 
    } 
}
```

}

**Example:**

Input:

```
{ 100 200 300 400 500 }
```

Output:

```
{ 100 500 300 200 400 }
```

What I would do is to print uncommon elements from the input with the output. 
So I would like to know how to define/store a generated array.

I tried different ways, I thought this one would work, but got no luck.

```
int[] arr1 = Arrays.toString(arr);
```

Comment: Save as in where? You need to agree on a serialized form(eg. JSON, CSV, etv) and use the same to persist.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi, what I meant was to define the generated array, just as I defined/declared my input: int arr[] = ....

Comment: You want the array generated from the original array passed as a parameter in the method  `generateWorstCase` ?

Comment: Use Arrays.copyOf

Comment: @dariosicily, yes that's what I want, but in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of your array in the beginning of your program using [Arrays.copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-), and then compare this old copy to your modified array (*note the below solution will only work in this case, because your array is of primitive values*):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
            10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
    int[] copyOfArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
    int n = arr.length;
    System.out.println("Sorted array is");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    generateWorstCase(arr, 0, n - 1);
    // You can do comparison here
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but I'd like to save the generated one, like did with the arr[], I would also like to print uncommon elements from the two arrays (input & output).

Comment: Hello, arr[] is your actual generated one, which you are are also printing at the end. The reason for this is that the array holds a "reference" to its values, and you are passing this reference into the methods, and you are then printing its own values (the values change, but the reference is the same). So your generated array is actually arr[] (output) and your input array is copyOfArr[].

Comment: Ahh, I understand it better now, when you tell it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of your original array with the method [Arrays.copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) and then pass the copy to your method `generateWorstCase` that will modify it:

```
int arr[] = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };
int n = arr.length;
int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(arr, n);
generateWorstCase(copy, 0, n - 1); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copy)); //will be printed [100, 500, 300, 200, 400]
```